# Rails App on Windows - Can't Access Remotely

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails app deployed on a machine in our network (windows).  Its running on port 80:

rails server -p 80 -e production

If I call localhost, the app loads fine.

However, if I call it from another machine on the network, it doesn't resolve: http://192.168.1.XXX

Any thoughts?

Comment: *it doesn't resolve* - what does it mean? Can you ping this host? Did you make an exception on that host's firewall to accept incoming connections?

Comment: This is more a "firewall" problem. Please, refer to this [superuser's post][1].


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/210091/how-does-one-allow-access-to-networked-pcs-to-see-your-localhost-in-iis7-win

Comment: jdoe: I can RDP to the host, but can't seem to ping the host or visit via http.

Comment: Zakaria: thanks - I've looked at the firewall settings, its different than the screenshot in the post you've referred to, but it seems like http traffic is setup.  

I'll check with our network person, the ping issue seems odd.